# How to filter group members in Microsoft graph API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I was sure about after reading Microsoft document that I can filter the group members using OData Query Parameters because https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members

Request GET URL - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members?filter= startswith(givenname,'V')

In above URL groupId is used from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

but when I try to get the result using Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) using my work account login, it's not working.

Also I have tried to use this in SDK (I have implemented graph API in my code using Microsoft graph API SDK) and still got same error.

And gives below error -

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "96f3ffef-56f5-42e3-82f2-64813106b729",
            "date": "2018-02-13T10:59:39"
        }
    }
}

Is this because "members" is not a resource type ? so it does not have properties and so we can not filter this result ?

If so then is there any other way we can get filtered group members ?

Also posted issue on Github - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2239

Comment: I believe it is because /members returns a list of ``directoryObject``s. Even though the ``user`` resource inherits from ``directoryObject``, you can't filter on ``givenName`` here. You would have to do client-side filtering to search for specific members.

Comment: Per my testing, both Microsoft graph and Azure AD graph could not support the filter query against group members as you mentioned. You may retrieve all the members under a specific group and filter them in your client as RasmusW commented. Or you could add your feature request to Microsoft Graph team.

Comment: @BruceChen thanks. Microsoft documentation should be corrected then that we can not filter group members.

Comment: I've created a UserVoice suggestion for this:
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35630488-enable-filter-on-group-members

Answer (score 4):

Add ConsistencyLevel: eventual to Your request header (should work for v1.0 and beta as well)

Comment: As of now, ConsistencyLevel header and $count query parameter are required for this filter to work. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-headers).

Comment: //testing the filter query here 
                // Get groups user is a member of
                // GET /me/memberOf
                var myfilteredUserGroups = await _graphClient.Me.MemberOf
                    .Request(queryOptions)
                    .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                    .Filter("startswith(displayName, 'sa')")
                    .Select("displayName,groupTypes,id")
                    .Top(GraphConstants.PageSize)
                    .GetAsync();

Answer (score 0):

[Filtering of group members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-to-get-group-membership-with-a-display-name-that-starts-with-the-letter-a-including-a-count-of-returned-objects) is now available [as a beta API](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35630488-enable-filter-on-group-members#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/members?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would impelment it in code

```
            //testing the filter query here 
            // Get groups user is a member of
            // GET /me/memberOf
            var myfilteredUserGroups = await _graphClient.Me.MemberOf
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                .Filter("startswith(displayName, 'sa')")
                .Select("displayName,groupTypes,id")
                .Top(GraphConstants.PageSize)
                .GetAsync();

            // This method casts the returned DirectoryObjects
            // as Group object, and filters out any non-Group objects
            model.MyFilteredGroups = await GetAllPagesAsType<Group>(
                _graphClient, myfilteredUserGroups);

            return View(model);
```